# How to remove @ prefix while converting xml to json in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, xmltodict, xml-to-json

I'm trying to convert xml to json in python using `xmltodict` library. Though, the xml is getting converted to json, before every key in dict, '@' is getting prefixed. Below is the code snippet and sample output:

```
import xmltodict
import json

with open('response.xml','r') as res_file:
    doc = xmltodict.parse(res_file.read())

xml_json_str = json.dumps(doc)
final_json = json.loads(xml_json_str)
```

Output:

```
"CustomerInfo": {
  "@address": "Bangalore, Karnataka 560034",
  "@email": "abc@gmail.com",
  "@name": "Sam",
}
```

How to remove @ from all key's at one go?

Comment: Can you show the contents of xml file ?

Comment: @Solen'ya: Below is the xml content.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<PIR:Data xmlns:PIR="https://google.com">
  <CustomerInfo address="Bangalore, Karnataka 560034" email="abc@gmail.com" name="Sam"/>
</PIR:Data>

Answer (score 5):

Finally I found a solution which works like charm. While parsing the xml, set `attr_prefix=''` to remove all @ from keys.

Below changes worked for me:

```
with open('response.xml','r') as res_file:
    doc = xmltodict.parse(res_file.read(), attr_prefix='')
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:
It will remove all the @ from all keys be it in any node: I have added one extra note just to show you the example:

```
def removeAtTheRate(jsonFile,final_json_edited):
    if jsonFile != {} and type(jsonFile) == dict:
        for i in jsonFile.keys():
            final_json_values = {}
            for j in jsonFile[i]:
                if j[:1] == '@':
                    final_json_values[j[1:]] = jsonFile[i][j]
            if i[:1] == '@':
                final_json_edited[i[1:]] = final_json_values
            else:
                final_json_edited[i] = final_json_values
    print(final_json_edited)

doc = {"@CustomerInfo":{"@address": "Bangalore, Karnataka 560034","@email": "abc@gmail.com","@name": "Sam"},"Location":{"@Loc":"Mum"}}
removeAtTheRate(doc,{})
```

Result:

```
>> {'Location': {'Loc': 'Mum'}, 'CustomerInfo': {'name': 'Sam', 'address': 
'Bangalore, Karnataka 560034', 'email': 'abc@gmail.com'}}
```

Comment: The solution by @steve.dev will give wrong output. It will delete the "C" from CustomerInfo key

Comment: @ Vaibhav Jadhav: Unfortunately your solution didn't work for my complex json.